# Flask (Working outside of application context) with RabiitMQ

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to build a consumer on a flask app and when i trying to get a data from another app (Django) to create it on flask database i got this error.

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

my consumer.py located in the same file of the main.py

consumer.py

```
# amqps://yildtheb:ZEATuey0rMa34bFIZ7NSmcUIQIhu4JFH@hawk.rmq.cloudamqp.com/yildtheb
import pika, json

from main import Product, db
params = pika.URLParameters('amqps://yildtheb:ZEATuey0rMa34bFIZ7NSmcUIQIhu4JFH@hawk.rmq.cloudamqp.com/yildtheb')

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(params)

channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue = 'main')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print('Message recieved')

    data = json.loads(body)
    print(data)
    print(properties.content_type)

    if properties.content_type == 'product created':
        print('product created')
        product = Product(id = data['id'], title = data['name'], image = data['image'])
        db.session.add(product)
        db.session.commit()

    elif properties.content_type == 'product updated':
        product = Product.query.get(data['id'])
        product.title = data['name']
        product.image = data['image']
        db.session.commit()

    elif properties.content_type == 'product deleted':
        product = Product.query.get(data)
        db.session.delete(product)
        db.session.commit()


channel.basic_consume(queue = 'main', on_message_callback = callback, auto_ack= True)

print('started consuming....')

channel.start_consuming()

channel.close()
```

How i can solve this error ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve it by adding this lines in consumer.py

```
from main import Product, db, app
from flask import current_app

app_ctx = app.app_context()
app_ctx.push()
```